# concatenation (string with int) value in Java

Tags: java, string, integer, concatenation

I would like to know why the result of the operation is: `200and100100`, and not as I expect (wrong assumption) `200and200`, I want to know the mechanism of such a result.

```
public class att {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String string1 = 100 + 100 + "and" + 100 + 100;
        System.out.println(string1);

    }
}
```

Comment: Order of evaluation, once it hits a `String` the entire operation becomes `String` concatenation. You can use `()` to force the order of evaluation. Or you can use a formatted `String`. Like `String string1 = String.format("%dand%d", 100+100, 100+100);`

Answer (score 2):

The rules are *evaluation from left to right* and

```
int + int    > addition      > int
String + int > concatenation > String
int + String > concatenation > String
```

In your case

```
int : 100
int with int : 100 > 200
int with String: "and" > 200and
String with int: 100 > 200and100
String with int: 100 > 200and100100
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are only using `+` it is interpreted from left to right.
If you put brackets around the right side, you should get what you expected.

```
String string1 = 100 + 100 + "and" + (100 + 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

The output you get is related to operator precedence and also the order of evaluation. In the absence of another rule, i.e. an operator of higher precedence, operators are evaluated in order from left to right.

Here, because all operators have the same precedence, because they're the same operator: +, and so the first operation is evaluated. Since it involves a String, it is String concatenation, and the result is a String; similarly for the following +.